# Why do these two forms of iteration produce different results?

Tags: python

```
alist = ['1', '2', '3']
blist = alist[:]

for x in alist:
    if not "@gmail.com" in alist:
        x = x + "@gmail.com"

for x in range(len(blist)):
    if not "@gmail.com" in blist[x]:
        blist[x] = blist[x] + "@gmail.com"
```

The first block of code does not implement what I need, yet the second one does.

What is the difference between these two blocks of code?

Comment: You could avoid this problem by using a list comprehension: `[x if '@gmail.com' in x else '{}@gmail.com'.format(x) for x in blist]`

Comment: Thanks! Your code works well for me! I also learned string.format() from you. Thank again! @pzp

Answer (score 2):

**Shorty: In first sample you aren't mutating list values, in second example you do.**

In first loop you  modifying `x`, which actually is copy of list item, but not that item,  in second sample you modifying item of list by accessing it by index. See [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python) to get more info regarding mutable and immutable types

However if you would apply loops on list which contain mutable types, the items would be modified by both `for` loops:

```
alist = [['1'], ['2'], ['3']]
blist = [['1'], ['2'], ['3']]

for x in alist:
    x.append("@gmail.com")
print alist    

for x in range(len(blist)):
    blist[x].append("@gmail.com")
print blist
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `x = x + "@gmail.com"` in the first version of the code, you're creating a new value and rebinding the name `x` to refer to it. This has no effect on `alist`, even though that's where the previous `x` value came from.

When you do `blist[x] = blist[x] + "@gmail.com"` on the other hand, you're explicitly modifying the list. You're rebinding `blist[x]` to refer to a new value.

Note that with different list contents, you might have been able to make the first version of the code work, using "in place" modification. Strings are immutable though, so there are no in-place operations. However, if `alist` contained mutable items such as `list`s, code like `x += ["foo"]` would extend the inner list in place. The `+=` operator will attempt to do an in place addition if the type of the object supports it (by having an `__iadd__` method). For types that don't support inplace operations though, it's just the same as `x = x + y`, which will have the same issue you've encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Your fist loop can be fixed to be:

```
for i, x in enumerate(alist):
    if "@gmail.com" not in x:
        alist[i] = x + "@gmail.com"
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
email="@gmail.com"
alist=[x+email if email not in x else x for x in alist]
```

Since `in` will return true if that string is anywhere in the string, `not x.endswith("@gmail.com")` is preferred in both cases above.

Comment: `not x.endwith("@gmail.com")` is brilliant!

Comment: Your list comprehension is wrong. The list it creates will not contain the list items that had `"@gmail.com"` in them to begin with.

Comment: @pzp: Thanks -- fixed

Answer (score 0):

Because strings are immutable:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

> Objects whose value can change are said to be mutable; objects whose
>   value is unchangeable once they are created are called immutable. (The
>   value of an immutable container object that contains a reference to a
>   mutable object can change when the latter’s value is changed; however
>   the container is still considered immutable, because the collection of
>   objects it contains cannot be changed. So, immutability is not
>   strictly the same as having an unchangeable value, it is more subtle.)
>   An object’s mutability is determined by its type; for instance,
>   numbers, strings and tuples are immutable, while dictionaries and
>   lists are mutable.

In the first example, you are creating a *new* variable named `x` each time you concatenate additional values to it.

I the second example, however, you are simply changing the value at the same index of your `list`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this has to do with strings being immutable. If `alist` was a list of lists, OP's first loop still would not work.

Comment: Yes, but OP expects that changing the value of `x` would in turn change the list element, but even though `x` is initially a reference to an element of `alist` (via `for`), it is re-initialized within the loop. If `x` was mutable, one could to something like `x.set_value(x + "@gmail.com")` but since it is immutable, they can't.

Comment: Okay, well to me this seems to have more to do with the nature of python iterators than it does the mutability of the objects within the iterable. I see where you're coming from though.

Comment: As I explained, if `x` was another (mutable) object, both loops could be written to work the same regardless of the nature of Python iterators.